# Proper procedure for installing CentOS on HP DL80

Tags: centos, raid, redhat, hp

I have a DL80 G9 on which I wish to install CentOS 6.7. I want my master boot partition to be a mirrored RAID 1 logical volume across 2 physical disks. I have additional storage that I will use to make another RAID 5 volume.

If I do a standard CentOS install on the DL80, the CentOS will have no knowledge of the logical RAID volumes I have set up with the HP system configuration. When CentOS asks me where it would like to do the install, it sees both of my 500GB disks when it should see 1 RAID 1 partition of 500GBs.

I downloaded the 2015.06.0 service pack, but the service pack stalls after a few minutes.

What is the proper way to install Centos 6.7 so that it can see my logical volumes?

Am I not setting up my BIOS properly?

Comment: First, can you tell us what RAID controller model is in your DL80? Second, did you use a driver disk?

Comment: The DL80 uses the HP Smart Array B140i Controller. I have not used a driver disk. Would this be used in conjunction with a CentOS install?

Comment: Yes. See below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The HP ProLiant DL80 Gen9 is a new small business focused server. It's pretty barebones and have a single non-swappable power supply.

You likely need to inject a [driver disk](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=7500990&swItemId=MTX_5b7be2d77c764b088ffa7ebbdf&swEnvOid=4103) into your initial CentOS installation because the server has a Smart Array B140i RAID controller:

Here is the [driver disk for RHEL/CentOS 6](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=7500990&swItemId=MTX_5b7be2d77c764b088ffa7ebbdf&swEnvOid=4103).

Here are the [instructions to *use* the driver disk](http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=7500990&swItemId=MTX_5b7be2d77c764b088ffa7ebbdf&swEnvOid=4103#tab3).

> MAKING DRIVER UPDATE USB-KEY UNDER A LINUX-LIKE OS:
>
> Save the "hpdsa-..x86_64.dd.gz" file into a
>   temporary directory. Use GUNZIP to extract
>   "hpdsa-..x86_64.dd" from this file into the same
>   directory. Insert the USB-Key. If the USB-Key is not mounted
>   automatically, then mount it. Copy the
>   hpdsa-..x86_64.dd file to the directory you USB-Key
>   is mounted to and then umount the USB-Key. INSTALLATION
>
> At the initial OS installation screen be sure to:
>
> For UEFI systems, press "e" to edit grub and append the parameters to
>   the "linuxefi" line. IMPORTANT: Remove the USB-Key once the driver has
>   been installed to prevent the OS installer from including the USB-Key
>   as part of the OS storage. blacklist=ahci dd

Comment: Thank you for the information. As for adding blacklist=ahci dd. Is there a special way that I should prepare the usb-key that has the dd file? Fat32?

Comment: Copy the file to a USB key.

Comment: I was able to load the image successfully as I was able to see it from the loader after I edited the GRUB commands, however, none of my logical drives that I created in the HB Array Controller are appearing.